# update array in database cakephp

Tags: database, arrays, cakephp

I have an array that looks like this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [image] => http://images0.jpg
        [title] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [image] => http://image1.jpg
        [title] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [image] => http://image2.jpg
        [title] => 
    )
```

And I save this array to database with saveAll, and when I unset for example key 2 from this array how to delete the corresponding record from the database which is not set?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this method for removing items from a database. Otherwise if you look for what's "not" in the array, you'll end up deleting all the rows!

Comment: So what is the best method? I want to compare the existing items with array and remove elements that doesnt exist. Im out of ideas. Can you give me some?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

add in the form extra field type of checkbox, you can add some javascript for better user experience.

the code could be something like this:

```
foreach($files as $key=>$file){
   echo '<div class="file" id="file_'.$key.'">';
   $this->Form->input("$key.title");
   $this->Form->input("$key.image");
   $this->Form->input("$key.deleted", array('type'=>'checkbox'));
   echo '</div>';
}
```

When the user click on the checkbox, a warning "Are you sure" can appear, and if the user click "Yes", then the surrounding div#file_XXX could be set to hidden.

This basically will hide the div, but the fields will be present when the user submits the form.

Then you can save the data with saveAll(), and later on delete the records which has deleted=1.

Basically your array will look like this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [image] => http://images0.jpg
        [title] => 
        [deleted]=>0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [image] => http://image1.jpg
        [title] => 
        [deleted]=>1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [image] => http://image2.jpg
        [title] => 
        [deleted]=>0
    )
```

The explanation is not very detailed, but hopefully it's understandable :)

Comment: Problem is that i dont have any forms and I read data from xml. I found a solution. First read data from database with key and image then use in_array($database_images, $xml_images) and write the result to new array, then delete images from this array from database, I hope you understand, For me it's working